# threading.resume and threading.suspend in obsolete

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

i want to write an application peer to peer program, this is my piece of code.

```
    public void ArrestaServer()
    {
        if (ThreadAscolta.ThreadState==ThreadState.Running)
            ThreadAscolta.Suspend();
    }

        public void AvviaServer()
        {
            if (ThreadAscolta == null)
            {
                ThreadAscolta = new Thread(ServerRicevi);
                ThreadAscolta.Start();
                while (!(ThreadAscolta.IsAlive)) ;
            }
            else if (ThreadAscolta.ThreadState==ThreadState.SuspendRequested)
                ThreadAscolta.Resume();
        }
```

How can i remove these alerts?

> System.Threading.Thread.Resume(): "Thread.Resume has been deprecated. 
>   Please use other classes in System.Threading, such as Monitor, Mutex,
>   Event, and Semaphore, to synchronize Threads or protect resources."
>
> System.Threading.Thread.Suspend(): "Thread.Suspend has been
>   deprecated.  Please use other classes in System.Threading, such as
>   Monitor, Mutex, Event, and Semaphore, to synchronize Threads or
>   protect resources."

Comment: Multi-threading isn't something you can do on a guessing basis. Using `Thread.Suspend` and `Thread.Abort` is a bad idea, and so is doing things like `while (!(ThreadAscolta.IsAlive));`. Try this for a starter - http://www.albahari.com/threading/ And I assume you're writing a network server - that shouldn't really use threads anyway. Just have a look at the asynchronous APIs for whatever network classes you're using.

Comment: *How can i remove these alerts?* it is right there in the warning. " Please use other classes in System.Threading, such as Monitor, Mutex, Event, and Semaphore, to synchronize Threads or protect resources"